# Kingmaker - how do the players buy/sell items (Possible spoilers)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, adventure-path

In the first book of Kingmaker, the AP provides guidance on how the players can sell their loot and acquire new items through Oleg.

Once the players start their kingdom, they have a city with a base value and item slots.  How is selling and acquiring items supposed to be handled?  Should they only be able to buy what is in their town?  Should Oleg still be able to acquire goods for them with a delay?  If they can get/sell whatever they want with a short delay, it seems useless to have shops in town at all.

Comment: *"it seems useless to have shops in town at all."* - just out of curiosity, aren't shops needed at all for daily lives of the other inhabitants of the city? I mean, in the game mechanics?

Comment: @Mołot In terms of roleplaying, yes.  Mechanically, with kingdom building rules, as long as you don't care what the base value of items you can buy is, then you can get along without.  (Of course the DM could bring in a storyline about how the citizens demand it)

Comment: It's notable that this situation isn't unique to Kingmaker. The Ruins of Azlant AP experiences a similar transition from "you can order nearly any item from the Metropolis, it will be here later" to "there are some things around to buy".

Answer (score 2):

### Just like normal

The [kingdom building rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/kingdom-building) do not change the other methods available to buy/sell equipment and magic items. Increasing your cities' purchase limit (*[Base value](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/kingdom-building/settlements/)*) will simply make those things available all the time (or at 75% chance), just like any other city. Oleg, being a merchant/trader, may still do his trading with Brevoy and take a few weeks to bring whatever item is requested from him.

Whatever is above the city's base value, may still be purchased at GM discretion (from [Settlements](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/kingdom-building/settlements/)):

> The base value of a settlement is used to determine what magic items may easily be purchased there. There is a 75% chance that any item of that value or lower can be found for sale in the settlement with little effort. The base value of a new settlement is 0 gp. Certain buildings (such as a Market or Tavern) increase a settlement’s base value. a settlement’s base value can never increase above the values listed in Table: Settlement Size and Base Value (except under special circumstances **decided by the GM**).

This *GM Fiat* is exactly considering specific scenarios like special requests, or paying things in advance so they can be sent to you, or even request for something to be crafted especially for you.

Note that, while a normal settlement has an initial base value of 0 gp, any city you build using the kingdom building rules is already considered a *Small Town* and has an initial base value of 500 gp instead.

Not only that but once your kingdom is established, you may also negotiate trade routes with other kingdoms, using **Trade Edicts**. While those edicts have a specific mechanic that affects the kingdom's economy, nothing prevents you from making requests to those traders to bring specific goods from other kingdoms.

Finally, I strongly recommend the third-party books from Legendary Games ([Ultimate Ruleship](https://paizo.com/products/btpy8zc7), [War](https://paizo.com/products/btpy98v1?Ultimate-War) and [Battle](https://paizo.com/products/btpy917u?Ultimate-Battle)), they are written by the same author of those rules originally (from Kingmaker), [Jason Nelson](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Jason_Nelson), and they expand the kingdom building rules and the mass combat rules in several ways, including fixing a few hiccups with the published rules.